# Nvim-dap: couldn't debug using gdb native on Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, gdb, neovim, neovim-plugin

In the last two months I've been migrating from VSCode to Neovim, and I've watched few videos about nvim configurations. After a while I've created a Neovim configuration I kinda like, but one thing that I cannot get to work is debugging in Neovim, as I was doing in VSCode. I tried using nvim-dap configured with [gdb native](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/wiki/Debug-Adapter-installation#ccrust-via-gdb), but anytime I try to start debugging I get an error saying that gdb didn't respond and couldn't start running the debug. I'm currently using **Neovim version 0.9.4**, **nvim-dap** installed with **Lazy.nvim** and the last Windows 11 version, with mingw gdb installed from **MSYS**.

*These are the nvim-dap configuration and the error message:*
[image: configutation]
[image: error message]

I've navigated through lots of forums and found nothing but "just read the docs" or "just use this other debugger", but no-one really explained why is this problem occurring or how to fix it. I'd like to know if there is a way of using nvim-dap with gdb native on a Windows enviroment or there is no other way than just installing another debugger.

**EDIT:**
After a suggestion in the comments I checked if at this point gdb does even start, and I found out that actually it does (I can see the process in the taskmanager), but it seems like it is not responding to Neovim requests.

Comment: It says `Check the logs for errors`, so what errors are in the logs?

Comment: I found the logs, but there was only this line:
**[ WARN ] 2023-12-22T21:22:55Z+0100 ] .../AppData/Local/nvim-data/lazy/nvim-dap/lua/dap.lua:681 ] "Request `terminate` timed out after 3000ms"**

Comment: and I think this refers to the fact that sometimes, after I get the error from nvim-dap, Neovim completely freezes because the debugger session can't terminate.

Comment: Is there really not more potentially useful info in the log file? Does gdb even start running?

Comment: I searched for a long time, but I didn't find anything else useful other than that log file, that doesn't contain anything else than that line. And from that error message I can understand that gdb probably never started